# Despertador em Python

Tags: python

Olá!

Estou a tentar fazer um despertador em Python, mas estou com problemas ao comparar o horário atual com o horário desejado para despertar, ele só aciona quando faço a condição If com != ao invés de ==.
O meu código está assim:

```
def relogio(): #função relogio
    horario.config(text = strftime("%H:%M"))
    horario.after(1000,relogio) #atualiza o horario a cada 1 segundo
    return
```

```
def ligAlarme(hora,minuto): #função alarme
   
    print(localtime().tm_hour)
    
    while True:
        
        if  localtime().tm_hour == int(hora) and localtime().tm_min == int(minuto):
            
            pygame.mixer.init() #chama o iniciador da música
            pygame.mixer.music.load("alarm-clock-ringing.mp3")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(loops = 2)
            botaoParar.place(x=325, y=210)
            
            break
         
        return
```

```
def deslAlarme(): #função para desligar o alarme
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    return
```

```
janela = tk.Tk()
janela.title("Despertador relógio")
janela.geometry("500x250")
janela.resizable(0,0) 
janela.config(bg = "white") 

horario = tk.Label(janela, bg = "white", fg = "black", font = "arial 50 bold") 
horario.pack() 
relogio()

hora = tk.Entry(janela, width = 2, bg = "white", fg = "black", font = "arial 25" ) 
hora.place(x=195,y=155)

minuto = tk.Entry(janela, width = 2, bg = "white", fg = "black", font = "arial 25" ) 
minuto.place(x=255,y=155)

botaoIniciar = tk.Button(janela, text = "Iniciar alarme", command = lambda: ligAlarme(hora.get(), minuto.get())) 
botaoIniciar.place(x=100,y=210)

botaoParar = tk.Button(janela, text = "Parar alarme", command = deslAlarme)

janela.mainloop()
```

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

O possível problemas talvez estaria no tipo de variável, por exemplo:

```
x = 1    #int()
y = '1'  #str()

x == y   #retorna False
```

No seu codigo você pode transformar um valor para *int()* ou outro para *str()*:

```
if  localtime().tm_hour == str(hora) and localtime().tm_min == str(minuto):
```

ou

```
if  int(localtime().tm_hour) == int(hora) and int(localtime().tm_min) == int(minuto):
```